# Can computing the reflexive closure of the transitive closure of a relation add more properties than just reflexivity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have the transitive closure of R, R+, and we then compute the reflexive transitive closure of R, which is R*, will the resultant set/relation ever have any additional properties other than reflexivity?

Comment: That depends on what you accept as a "property".

Comment: Just the following properties: reflexive, irreflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, asymmetric, transitive

Comment: Among those properties, it is easy to verify that the only one $R^*$ can have without $R^+$ having it is reflexivity.

Answer (score 0):

- transitive: $R^+$ has it.
- reflexive: $R^+$ may not have it, $R^*$ has it. Part of the assumptions.
- symmetric: Take $<$ on any nontrivial totally ordered set. It's already transitive, and $<^* = ≤$, which is not symmetric.
- irreflexive: of course $R^+$ does not have it.
- antisymmetric + asymmetric: use a nonstrict partial order, like $<$ on polynomials as $p<q \iff \deg(p) ≤ \deg(q) $, which is already transitive and reflexive. And of course not antisymmetric, nor asymmetric!